# Connecting 2 Nodes on the Same Level

Tags: graphs

I'm a bit lost on connecting 2 nodes together that are not children. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{graph}{2.5in}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        level distance = 2.5cm,
        level 1/.style = {sibling distance=4.0cm},
        level 2/.style = {sibling distance=5.5cm},
        level 3/.style = {sibling distance=5.0cm},
     every node/.style = {circle,draw},
            lbl/.style = {rectangle, draw=none, #1,% position
                          font=\footnotesize}
                             ]
     \node (Root) {Start}
         child {node {Node 1}
             child {node {Node 4}
                 child {node {Goal 1}
                 edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$3$}
                 }
             edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$3$}
            }
         edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$3$}
           }
         child { node {Node 2}
            child{ node {Goal 2} 
            edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$12$}}
            edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$12$}
         }
         child { node {Node 3}
             child { node {Node 6} 
                child {node {Node 8}
                child {node {Goal 3}
                edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}}
                edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}}
                edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}}
                edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}
               };
         \end{tikzpicture}

\end{graph}
```

I would like to connect Goal 2 to Node 4.

Comment: Welcome! Please make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! All the nodes except for `Start` are children. Which of those do you want t connect?

Comment: Very good point. In this case I'm looking to connect Node 4 with Goal 2. They're all children of the Root node (start). I hope the code snippet is compilable now (I copy and posted the entire thing).

Comment: Thanks for improving your code! It is missing an appropriate `\documentclass` as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nodes get named automatically. This makes connecting them straightforward.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    level distance = 2.5cm,
    level 1/.style = {sibling distance=4.0cm},
    level 2/.style = {sibling distance=5.5cm},
    level 3/.style = {sibling distance=5.0cm},
 every node/.style = {circle,draw},
        lbl/.style = {rectangle, draw=none, #1,% position
                      font=\footnotesize}
                         ]
 %
 \node (Root) {Start}
     child {node {Node 1}
         child {node {Node 4}
             child {node {Goal 1}
             edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$3$}
             }
         edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$3$}
        }
     edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$3$}
       }
     child { node {Node 2}
        child{ node {Goal 2} 
        edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$12$}}
        edge from parent node[lbl=left] {$12$}
     }
     child { node {Node 3}
         child { node {Node 6} 
            child {node {Node 8}
            child {node {Goal 3}
            edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}}
            edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}}
            edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}}
            edge from parent node[lbl=right] {$1$}
           };
\draw (Root-1-1) -- (Root-2-1) node[midway,above,lbl]{$7$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just picked up latex recently and was not aware of using \draw. Is there a way to add a value between the arc?

Comment: @user8738587 Of course. I added a label.